# Qt: Dragging a widget to scroll the widget's parent QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, draggable

I've got a long horizontal QLabel displaying a png (the image shows a signal/time graph). Under that, I've got a QTableWidget. Both of these are in a QScrollArea because I want them to stay vertically aligned (the cells in the table correspond with the signal seen directly above them). I'm trying to add a handler to the QLabel such that the user can use the picture itself to scroll the scrollarea, rather than having to use the scrollbar. Is there a tried-and-tested way to do this? Directly setting the scrollarea's sliderPosition inside the QLabel's dragMoveEvent doesn't seem smart, because when the scrollarea scrolls it also leads to another dragMoveEvent on the (moving) QLabel.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping the combination (including the scroll area) in their own widget, and overriding the `dragMoveEvent()` on that widget.  The `dragMoveEvent()` shouldn't be triggered when you change the scroll position if you are doing it this way, I wouldn't think, although I haven't actually tested it.